# MongoDB: use $sum with multiple $cond

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want calculate points based to the size of an array element.
I can use $sum with multiple $cond?

Something like this:

```
    {
    $project: {
      points: {
        $sum: [
          {
            $cond: [
              {
                $and: [{ $gt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$matches", 0] }, 0] }, { $gt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$matches", 1] }, 0] }, { $gt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$matches", 2] }, 0] }],
              },
              10,
              0,
            ],
          },
          {
            $cond: [
              {
                $and: [{ $gt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$matches", 3] }, 0] }, { $gt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$matches", 4] }, 0] }, { $gt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$matches", 5] }, 0] }],
              },
              10,
              0,
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
```

This script always returns 20 even if not all conditions are true

Example of document:

```
{ 
"_id" : NumberInt(5), 
"total_matches" : NumberInt(0), 
"matches" : [
    [

    ], 
    [

    ], 
    [

    ], 
    [

    ], 
    [

    ], 
    [

    ], 
    [

    ], 
    [

    ], 
    [

    ]
]
```

}

OUTPUT

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(5), 
    "points" : 20.0, 
    "matches" : [
        [

        ], 
        [

        ], 
        [

        ], 
        [

        ], 
        [

        ], 
        [

        ], 
        [

        ], 
        [

        ], 
        [

        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample documents and result output? Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun of course, I have edited the post

Comment: You are checking if `[]` is greater than 0

Comment: What do you want to check?

Comment: Do you want to give 10 points if first 3 items exist and 20 if first 6 exist?

Comment: In your query all conditions are true as you have more than 6 `[]` inside `matches` array, and each of them is greater than 0

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/LcpvXIzDy7h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that I forgot $size in the query.
The right query is this:

```
 {
    $project: {
      points: {
        $sum: [
          {
            $cond: [
              {
                $and: [{ $gt: [{ $size:{ $arrayElemAt: ["$matches", 0] }}, 0] }, { $gt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$matches", 1] }, 0] }, { $gt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$matches", 2] }, 0] }],
              },
              10,
              0,
            ],
          },
          {
            $cond: [
              {
                $and: [{ $gt: [{ $size:{ $arrayElemAt: ["$matches", 3] }}, 0] }, { $gt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$matches", 4] }, 0] }, { $gt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$matches", 5] }, 0] }],
              },
              10,
              0,
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  }
```